# Jenkins Multibranch Pipelines - Configuring properties in branches?

Tags: git, jenkins, build, branch, jenkins-pipeline

We have successfully set up a build pipeline using the Jenkins Multibranch Pipeline Plugin, which works great most of the time, but we have this problem which nags us: The `Jenkinsfile` contains a set of properties, and these also show up in the UI, but how can I set up default values for individual branches?

This is how the properties definitions look like in our `Jenkinsfile`:

```
properties([
    parameters([
        string(defaultValue: 'somevalue', description: 'Some description', name: 'SOME_VALUE'),
        string(defaultValue: 'asdfasdfasdfasdfdasdasdasdasd...', description: 'Client ID', name: 'TEST_CLIENT_ID'),
        // ... more properties
        string(defaultValue: '', description: 'Enter non-empty value to skip tests', name: 'SKIP_TESTS'),
    ]), 
    [$class: 'RebuildSettings', autoRebuild: true, rebuildDisabled: false],
    pipelineTriggers([])
])
```

I do have a "Show Configuration" for each branch build pipeline (pipelines are generated automatically), and I can enter values when doing a "Build with parameters", but I can't seem to save the branch default values? There simply is no "Save" button for that.

Have we misconfigured Jenkins, or do I do this somewhere else? What I want to achieve is to be able to define default values for properties on a per-branch basis.

**Installed Versions**:

- Jenkins version: 2.19.4
- Multibranch Pipeline Plugin version: 2.9.2

Comment: Just to clarify: do you have different default values on different branches? And it doesnt work?

Comment: Exactly. Or better said: That's what I want to have. In source code, I can just specify one default value (or?).

Comment: From my understanding each branch has its own version of Jenkinsfile. Hence you can change the defaults independently. On each branch it will be constant but different across branches.

Comment: Yes, of course, but this doesn't really help, as those changes would usually also be merged to master afterwards, which in best case just creates a lot of merge conflicts, but worst case mixes up things. In our case these are things like client ids used for resolving the redirect URI in an OAuth authorization scenario. These need to be different, as the feature builds are deployed to different locations.

Comment: Can you make them computable? I.e. store somewhere a db (or just a text file in src) and retrieve using the metadata from current commit, or branch name, or REST API request to SCM server.

Comment: That's we ended up doing (storing in source control), but I don't like it. In the end, your suggestions suggest :-) that it's simply not possible to do a per-branch changing of the property defaults, currently. That is, not without tapping into a different data store or by adding the data to source control. I still think it would make sense though (and the UI is _almost_ there).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the form with the double-quoted string

```
string(defaultValue: "branch-${env.GIT_BRANCH}", description: 'Some description', name: 'SOME_VALUE')
```

in setting the default values of the parameters (as you describe in your question)

It's limited by the fact that when the 'properties' step is executed in one build, it sets the parameter defaults that appear on the next build. This is because the parameter entry is done before the Jenkinsfile is even available.